# How to remove seconds on datetimepicker?

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I have a modal which contains forms and every forms has a datetimepicker.I used format but unfortunately it didn't work. I've looked other answers however things didn't change for me. How can i remove seconds on datetimepicker input ?

```
   $('.sessiondate').each(function () {
        $(this).datetimepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            format: 'dd.mm.yyyy HH:mm',
            language: 'tr',
            startDate: new Date(),
            useCurrent: false,
            forceParse: false,
        }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
            $(this).datetimepicker('hide');
        });
    });
```

Comment: Which datetimepicker are you using? Can you share the link?

Comment: https://keenthemes.com/metronic/preview/?page=crud/forms/widgets/bootstrap-datepicker&demo=default

Comment: Sorry. Can't see any documentation anywhere. If you can point to a link where docs are present, someone can help you. If it's not available or behind some kind of a license, then only somebody else with this license can.

Comment: Sorry. Here is the link. 
https://keenthemes.com/metronic/?page=docs&section=references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your demo link, I have found they have used following thing to stop seconds.

```
$("#kt_datetimepicker_1").datetimepicker({  
   todayHighlight:!0,
   autoclose:!0,
   format:"yyyy.mm.dd hh:ii"
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$('#dateTime').datetimepicker({format : 'YYYY-MM-DD  HH:mm A'});</script>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.